# C# Reporting will not repeat fields on new page in PDF/print mode

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting, reportviewer, rdlc

My report has nested lists and in the innermost list I have a table:

```
page header
page body
  list1
    list2
      table
page footer
```

On every new page, both in printing/PDF and normal browsing mode I see the page header and the table header. So far so good.

What I would like to see on every page is the contents of `list 1` and `list 2`.

I set the `RepeatWith` property for the `list 1` items to `list 2`, and for the `list 2` items to `table`. This works fine in browsing mode, every page starts with the page header, followed by `list 1`, followed by `list 2`, followed by the `table` header followed by the `table` data for that page. In print mode I can only see the page header and the `table` header however.

Am I missing something obvious? I'm using VS2008 by the way with `ReportViewer` 9.0 in an ASP.NET project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same problem here. Unfortunately, from [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/349132/repeatwith-not-working-when-printing):

> The behavior you are seeing is by design. The RepeatWith functionality is not supported in "physical pagination" renderers: Print, Image, and PDF.

The suggested workaround is to put everything into the table header and set it to repeat on every page. This may work in some cases where the table already spans the entire width of the page, or at least is as wide as the header information.

However, I am using column groups so the header is much wider than the rest of the matrix, so this isn't an option for me and it probably wouldn't work here either...

Comment: @Blindy So other people like me who come here searching for an answer can at least get one rather than just a open-ended question? Just because the question is a year old doesn't mean it isn't still valid.

Comment: Still a valid question after 8 years.  (Also, Microsoft Connect is dead.  Long live Microsoft Docs.)

Answer (score 0):

HI- I was having a possibly similar problem, with report headers not appearing on each page of a report when printing, and this article provided the solution. May not be too helpful in your case, as you are dealing with sub-lists, but maybe some of the properties mentioned there will provide more avenues for investigation:
[What to do when RepeatColumnHeaders doesnt work](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2010/06/14/what-to-do-when-the-repeatcolumnheaders-property-in-a-tablix-isn-t-working.aspx)

Good luck

YS

Comment: I came across that article earlier too and it didn't really help me.